# NSBundle mainBundle appStoreReceiptURL - different result in one by one launches

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

`NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]]`

I'm testing in-app purchases. When I try to test a subscription in Sandbox while activation all seems to be ok. In the first re-launch too.

But in the second relaunch the data is suddenly changed (and the results of purchases are changed too). Why? May be the reason is that I've changed the test account to another one?

```
NSLog(@"manager lu %lu",(unsigned long)[subscriptionProduct.receipt length]);
        NSLog(@"manager receipt %@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]);
```

this code above gives for first two times this:

> manager lu 20306 
>   manager receipt file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DC144D8C-608F-46D5-A9BB-34F8E76E1DBC/StoreKit/sandboxReceipt

and this

> manager lu 20306 
>   manager receipt file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/832D788D-728A-463F-B94A-A8DA6E266647/StoreKit/sandboxReceipt

but for the last launch this:

> manager lu 35244 manager receipt
>   file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8B35BA0F-AF4C-4551-A90C-C2690C2DFFE6/StoreKit/sandboxReceipt

What the hell is this?

Comment: This is normal. It doesn't matter.

Comment: lol. how to catch this ? why it occurs?

Comment: There's nothing to catch. An app's sandbox can change. It's normal.